# Sum over function with changing parameters in libre office calc

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have a spreadsheet that MWE to:

| a | b | c |

|---|---|---|

| 1 | 3 | 5 |

| 2 | 4 | 6 |

I would like to have a new column, where I calculate the sum of all `a_n*exp(-(x-b_n)^2/c_n)`, where `x` would be a parameter given in another column and n is the row.

I would think this would be something the likes of`=SUM(A2:A3*EXP(-($D3-B2:B3)^2/C2:C3))` but this doesn't work (here the `D` column holds the x values)

Answer (score 2):

It is called spreadsheet calculation. So we should using the sheet having multiple cells. If we need sum of all values, we do calculating the single values first and then we sum them using `SUM` function.

Example:

[image]

Formulas:

`D5` = `=$A5*EXP(-(D$3-$B5)^2/$C5)` copied down and to right to `F12`.

Because the row references in `$A5`, `$B5` and `$C5` are relative (not fixated using `$`) those row references will be updated while copying downwards. And because the column reference in `D$3` also is relative this column reference will be updated while copying sidewards.

`D13` = `=SUM(D5:D12)` copied to right to `F13`.

All in one is only possible using formulas in array context. The function `SUMPRODUCT` takes all of its parameters in array context.

Formula in `D15` = `=SUMPRODUCT($A$5:$A$12*EXP(-(D$3-$B$5:$B$12)^2/$C$5:$C$12))`

Another possibility would be using array context in `SUM` function:

Formula `=SUM($A$5:$A$12*EXP(-(D$3-$B$5:$B$12)^2/$C$5:$C$12))` - results in `#VALUE!`. Then click `fx` and tick check-box `[x] Array`:

[image]

Comment: I want to pull over multiple ‘x‘ values, so that's why I want to use the something like ’SUMPRODUCT’. I sadly cannot seem to get that to work. Did I have a mistake in using ’*’ for multiplication (you have a ^ between a and exp consistently)

Comment: @Thorbjørn E. K. Christensen: Updated for using multiple x. The `^` instead of  `*` was because I misread your formula first.